# Does Godel's Incompletenss Theorem mean there is no solution to Hilbert's 6th Problem?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

If the stated question is true then what are the consequencies to mathematical physics as an aspect of Hilbert's 6th Problem.

Comment: The short answer to the question is no.  As it stands, the question is either trivial or too vague and unfocused to be appropriate to MO. Voting to close.

Comment: Please read http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask and http://mathoverflow.net/faq.  One of the requirements to ask a good question is that you put a lot of thought into it yourself, and make that effort clear.  I vote to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The incompleteness theorem does not say anything about whether a particular informal theory is capable of being formalized. The incompleteness theorem only applies to formal theories, so it doesn't tell us anything about a theory that has not yet been formalized. You might want to read a book by Franzen called Godel's Theorem: An Incomplete Guide to Its Use and Abuse.

Comment: I will try to read the book.